# wordpress add a "variable" to a page body (perhaps a markup tag)

Tags: php, wordpress, dynamic, tags

I am sorry for my inexperience in Wordpress, searching for terms like "variable" don't hone in on the specific concept I'm wanting to achieve.  I also tried terms like dynamic content block.

How do I include an HTML tag which is recognized as either an included php file, or a call to a function, that will ultimately lead to an external PHP file?  For example:

```
<p> here is paragraph 1 </p>

{{widget_name_here}} <!-- this would be replaced by a php file or include -->

<p> here is paragraph 3 </p>
```

-- EDIT --
I am going to Pages > New Page and in the large text area, this is where I'm entering HTML content.  This is where I would like to add some type of tag like `{{widget_name_here}}`

In addition, there is a column to the right that says `Page Attributes`, and for template I am selecting Default Template.

Oh, I need to do this without any plugins due to constraints.  I'm pretty sure WP has a native way to do this.  Thanks

Comment: Are you adding this code to a template file or in a post/page directly?

Comment: Edited the post above to clarify that.

Comment: You can't do that without a plugin. Search wordpress.org for insert php or something